# How to add text to element using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Coming back to jquery after long time trying to add text to text area , with the below logic i dont see text at the level i am trying to put in html. what would be correct approach to get expected result ?

main.js

```
    function updateRequest(ref, version) {
        if (SDKresult[ref]) {
            if (SDKresult[ref].request) {
                delete SDKresult[ref].request.env;
                SDKresult[ref].request['nodeEnv'] = SDKresult['nodeEnv'];
                SDKresult[ref]['app'] = "require['/wrapper-sdk']";
            }

            $('#request_method_JS').text(ref + '(' + JSON.stringify(SDKresult[ref].request, null, 4) + ', function(result) {\n //Your code goes here \n debugger; \n console.log(result); \n});');
        }
    }
```

main.html

```
 <pre id="request_method_JS" style="margin: 5px;"></pre>
```

current Result

```
App.Member.Details({
    "apiKey": "769c71dfa4ef3",
    "tokenId": "587218f552"
}, function(result) {
 //Your code goes here 
 debugger; 
 console.log(result); 
});
```

Expected output in textArea should be

```
var app = require('/wrapper-sdk');

app.Api.setConfig({
            "env": "DEV"
        });

App.Member.Details({
    "apiKey": "769c71dfa4ef3",
    "tokenId": "587218f552"
}, function(result) {
 //Your code goes here 
 debugger; 
 console.log(result); 
});
```

Comment: Braces aren't balanced in the function definition.

Comment: @Barmar i fixed the braces i minimize the code for better understanding missed the braces, thanks for catching that.

Comment: How is the `require` line supposed to get into the output?

Comment: Your function also never puts the `app.Api.setConfig` code in the output.

Comment: yes output would be a sample code for client so they can copy/paste to write new code for the particular operation.

Comment: What does that mean? I asked where the code is that's supposed to create that output.

Comment: its in first main.js in updateRequest function that is appending the text

Comment: I understand that, but the only text it's appending is the part that begins with `App.Member.Details`, which I assume is the value of `ref`. It never appends the `var app =` line or the `app.Api.setConfig` code.

Comment: thats why i asked question how would i append the text for the `app` so i can get expected result

Comment: is `var app = require('/wrapper-sdk'); app.Api.setConfig...` supposed to get from ref?

Comment: @Jose Rojas No its not ref property right now i am creating variable to append it later it will be added dynamically will be passed to updateRequest method, for now my idea is to append text the way it is in expected response.

Comment: So, stick the require line and the setConfig line in another variable and append it before the `ref`?

Comment: @Taplar correct

Comment: Right..... i'm saying do that to solve your problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything you want to write into a variable, then call `.text()` with that.

```
function updateRequest(ref, version) {
    if (SDKresult[ref]) {
        if (SDKresult[ref].request) {
            delete SDKresult[ref].request.env;
            SDKresult[ref].request['nodeEnv'] = SDKresult['nodeEnv'];
            SDKresult[ref]['app'] = "require('/wrapper-sdk')";
        }

        var text = '';
        text += 'var ref = ' + SDKresult[ref].app + ';\n\n';
        text += 'app.Api.setConfig({\n    "env": "DEV"\n});\n\n';
        text += ref + '(' + JSON.stringify(SDKresult[ref].request, null, 4) + ', function(result) {\n //Your code goes here \n debugger; \n console.log(result); \n});';
        $('#request_method_JS').text(text);
    }
}
```